# How can I save to database when new image is selected. If not, leave old pictures in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

If I try with my code to save new pictures, or to leave old pictures in the database, it will not work.

I have rewritten the code several times but can not get it.

This is my Code. I hope someone can help me.

```
    $files = "";


if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){


    $files = $_FILES['files'];


    $ergebnis = "SELECT FILE_NAME FROM auktion_images WHERE ANGEBOT_ID = '{$change}'";
    $resultat = $pdo->query($ergebnis);
foreach ($resultat as $reihe): ?>
            <?php unlink('image_uploads/'.$reihe["FILE_NAME"]); 
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("delete from auktion_images where ANGEBOT_ID = '{$change}'");
            $statement->execute(array());
            endforeach;

    $query = "INSERT into auktion_images(`ANGEBOT_ID`, `FILE_NAME`, `FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`)
             VALUES(:ANGEBOT_ID, :FILE_NAME, :FILE_SIZE, :FILE_TYPE)";
    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
        if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' wurde nicht hochgeladen.';
            continue;
        }

        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[] = 'Bilder müssen kleiner als 2 MB sein.';
            continue;
        }
        try{
            $stmt->bindParam( ':ANGEBOT_ID', $change, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_NAME', $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_SIZE', $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_TYPE', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $desired_dir="image_uploads";

            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
            }else{    //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file) ;               
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $errors[] = $file_name . 'nicht in Datenbank gespeichert.';
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }}
    elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($files)){
```

The best thing that has happened so far is that I can save new pictures.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example of the problem?  Where does `$files` come from?  What is the runtime value of the variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: $files = "";                                             
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($files)){ 
$files = $_FILES['files'];
}else if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($files)){ 
$files = $_FILES['files'];

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){ $files = $_FILES['files']; }elseif(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //form submit without select a picture ...}
`

Comment: It does not work

Comment: "it does not work" is a unless statement. Is there a php error? Is there a MySQL error? Is there some behaviour that it didn't do? You can edit the question rather than putting comments, its easier to read.

Comment: If you do not select images, the old images will still be deleted.

Comment: How "select images" relates to the code here isn't clear. There is no code for "delete images" either. Your lack of verbose description will ultimately result in no answer. The first comment here said exactly the same thing. Last chance.

Comment: $files = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])){

$files = $_FILES['files'];

else if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_FILES['files'])){ insert only none image data

Comment: $ergebnis = "SELECT FILE_NAME FROM auktion_images WHERE ANGEBOT_ID = '{$change}'";
    $resultat = $pdo->query($ergebnis);
foreach ($resultat as $reihe): ?>
            <?php unlink('image_uploads/'.$reihe["FILE_NAME"]); 
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("delete from auktion_images where ANGEBOT_ID = '{$change}'");
            $statement->execute(array());
            endforeach;

Comment: I tryed this:   $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `auktion_images` (ANGEBOT_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE) 
SELECT `ANGEBOT_ID`, `FILE_NAME`, `FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE` FROM `auktion_images` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `auktion_images` 
      WHERE ANGEBOT_ID='$change')");
    
$result = $statement->execute();   But it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){ ... }
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){ ...}
```